# Error installing bower version 1.8.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, bower, npm-install, bower-install

i am trying to install bower version 1.8.2
globally on my Ubuntu 16.04

but it show that Missing write access /usr/local/bin

**i have node 4.2.6
and npm 3.5.2
i get this** error:

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$ npm install -g bower
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib
`-- bower@1.8.2 

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Python-2.7.14/npm-debug.log
ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$ node --version
v4.2.6
ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$ npm --version
3.5.2
ubuntu@ubuntu-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.14$
```

Comment: well the problem is with your permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using sudo:

```
sudo npm i --global bower
```

But that is not recommended, hence you can fix your npm permissions like this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/lib/node_modules
```

You can find a [gist for the same here.](https://github.com/mixonic/docs.npmjs.com/blob/master/content/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.md)